# What are the highest level solo monsters in all official supplements released for 4th Edition Dungeons & Dragons?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

Which is the highest level solo monster in all current supplements released for DnD 4.0? I think that it is Bahamut, but there are too many books which I'm not aware of (and also I have read somewhere that Bahamut is level 36, I don't own the concrete book).

Also which monster is the hardest to beat by average balanced team (nor anti-Orcus, or anti-Tiamat team configuration)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two level 36 creatures are:

- [Bahamut](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=4218) (Draconomicon: Metallic Dragons)
- [The Old Man with the Canaries](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=4217) (Draconomicon: Metallic Dragons)

There are no higher level creatures, and arguably those two creatures are just alternate forms of Bahamut.

[Lolth](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=5047) (MM3), level 35 from MM3 looks to be very nasty. Lots of domination spam, coupled with non-trivial amounts of ongoing and published in the latest MM make for a fun, but nasty creature.
As a runner up, I'd also be quite scared of [Bel Shalor, the Shadow in the Flame](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=3224) (Ebberon Campaign Setting) as many of his attacks do healing surge damage and he acts on three initiative counts. His effect-shedding is not quite as good as Lolths (though it triggers three times as often) and his attacks aren't particularly scary when compared to Lolth's dominate multiple people per turn.

Comment: I don't have a DndInsider subscription, so the links don't work for me. :(

Comment: The OP asked for *current supplements released for DnD 4.0*. I don't know if those creatures are form a supplement book or exclusive to DDI. If so I'm not sure if it qualifies as a 'good' answer, as it's not what they asked for (afaik).

Comment: Very few things are "exclusive to DDI"

Comment: Thanks for adding the book titles for these. Very Helpful now :)

Answer (score -3):

I think this answer sums that up quite nicely. However, a thread on WotC forums has tharizdun and moradin, both level 40.
http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3331206

Comment: Those don't seem to be official creatures.

Comment: A [search of the Compendium](http://i.imgur.com/B0bHOGh.png) with Creatures sorted in reverse level order suggests that _Bahamut_ and _The Old Man with the Canaries_ remain the two highest-level creatures. If there are official level 40 creatures, or if there's a Moradin or Tharizdun, they're not in the compendium.

Comment: if you read my post, you would see that they were homebrew on a forum, created by someone who just wanted to share the essentials versions of the gods (and demon lords in another post)

Comment: By the way, Jonathan, you should have clicked on the link in order to see the post. It's very good, as long as you can get over the fact that it's not official